# Geocoder not working in Android 2.2 and beyond

Tags: android-2.2-froyo, android-sdk-2.1, android-maps, android-sdk-2.3

I have been using Geocoder class for looking city names and geolocation.

It is working till 2.1, but is saying "Service not available" in 2.2 and 2.3

any workaround!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found that its an issue with the Emulator, but not with the real devices.